# JQuery UI dialog trigger from parent dialog button click

Tags: jquery

I've searched all over for the answer to this.  I've found similar issues and attempted their recommendations, all to no avail, so I'm trying to post my issue here.  Please forgive any duplication.  Also, I'm an experienced Javascripter but a jQuery noob.

My Problem: I have a modal jQuery UI dialog with a button btnStates (not in the parent dialog's buttons array, but in the div).  Upon clicking the button, I want it to popup a second modal dialog of a div I have in the html with its display set to none.  The div contains only a simple select element of state options.  The user must select a state and press OK, or Cancel to return to the parent dialog.

I can't get it to work.  In one configuration of the code, it would popup my states dialog upon document.ready, but ignore that I had coded it to the click event.  Can someone tell me where my jQuery is wrong to achieve this?  Here is my lastest attempt at the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $( "#dlgInstitutionSearch" ).dialog(
        { 
            dialogClass: "no-close", minWidth:512, minHeight:410, closeOnEscape:true, 
            buttons: [ 
                { text: "Search", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }, 
                { text: "Cancel", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }, 
                { text: "Help", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } 
            ] 
    });

    $("#btnStates").click(function(){
        $("#dlgStatesList").dialog({
            dialogClass: "no-close", minWidth:200, minHeight:300, closeOnEscape:true, 
            buttons: [ 
                { text: "OK", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }, 
                { text: "Cancel", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }
            ] 
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to initialize the "inner" dialog in one step and open it in another like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $( "#dlgInstitutionSearch" ).dialog(
        { 
            dialogClass: "no-close", minWidth:512, minHeight:410, closeOnEscape:true, 
            buttons: [ 
                { text: "Search", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }, 
                { text: "Cancel", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }, 
                { text: "Help", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } 
            ] 
    });

    // Initialize the dialog
    $("#dlgStatesList").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: "no-close", minWidth:200, minHeight:300, closeOnEscape:true, 
        buttons: [ 
            { text: "OK", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }, 
            { text: "Cancel", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }
        ] 
    });

    // Open state dialog on click
    $("#btnStates").click(function(){
        $("#dlgStatesList").dialog("open");
    });

});
```

EDIT: Added a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mmeNS/

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.  I cut and pasted your code into mine, but btnStates still does nothing upon clicking it.  Anything else to try?

Comment: You should also check the states dialog z-index.  Is it maybe showing up behind the other dialog?  Also, are you receiving any errors?  Creating a jsFiddle might also help me to debug.

Comment: @JLeRogue - I added a working example that uses the above code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmeNS/).

Comment: That did it!  Thank you SO MUCH!  The difference: My div was using name="btnStates" instead of id="btnStates".  The JQuery samples from which I was learning used "name=" for the most part, though in the past I had typically used "id=" because of the getElementById command in javascript.